# Checking for attributes in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing some data from HTML by walking through elements at a certain level using nextSibling, and doing different things depending on the tag name and class of each element encountered.

e.g.,

```
if n.name == "p" and n.class == "poem": blah()
```

But this raises an error if the element doesn't have a class or if it isn't an instance of Tag and hence has no name.

Testing before accessing like this

```
if "name" in n:
```

always return false. I could check the type of the object returned by nextSibling to try to weed out NavigableString and Comment, but there's got to be an easier way.

EDIT

Emailed the dev of BeautifulSoup with this question and he recommended testing with

```
n.get("class")
```

which returns None if "class" is unset, which makes it possible to just do:

```
if n.get("class") == "poem": blah()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Besides using `get()` method

```
n.get("class")
```

Another option is to use `has_attr()` (use `has_key()` pre BeautifulSoup 4):

```
n.has_attr("class")
```

Comment: In BeautifulSoup 4 ````n.has_key()```` has been deprecated and ````n.has_attr("class")```` is preferred

Answer (score 8):

In this case exceptions may be your friend:

```
try:
    if n.name == 'p' and n['class'] == "poem":
        blah()
except AttributeError: # element does not have .name attribute
    do_something()
except KeyError: # element does not have a class
    do_something_else()
```

You may also wrap it into one `except` if this is in case:

```
try:
    if n.name == 'p' and n['class'] == "poem":
        blah()
except (AttributeError, KeyError):
    pass
```

Comment: Hey, this really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. If you're dealing with lists, you may want `child.name in namelist` and `any(c in child['class'] for c in classlist)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this~:

`if class in n.attrs`

Comment: Doesn't work since `n.attrs` is a list with tuples like this: `[(u'class', u'my-class'), (u'id', u'my-id')]`. You'll need to turn the list into a `dict` first.

Answer (score -1):

Why not?

```
if hasattr(n,"name"):
```

Comment: For an element n, I am getting "hasattr(n, "class") - True. "n['class']" - Key Error: class.

Comment: hasattr(n,"class") == true implies n.class exists, not n["class"]

Comment: Referencing "n.class" yeilds "Syntax Error" (I believe because "class" is a keyword")? "hasattr(n, "class") is also giving me false positives, hence more Key Errors.

Comment: Read the beautifulsoup docs, they describe the options for dealing with markup attributes that conflict with python reserved words. But your fundamental problem is you're confusing attribute access eg x.y with item access x[y]. They aren't the same thing in python.

Comment: I've been banging my head against the BeautifulSoup docs, and I don't see the answer to my question. They address using the attr dictionary for attributes that conflict with python keywords, but only in the context of search. I'm not searching - I've got an element and I'm just trying to see if it has a class. n["class"] successfully accesses the class when it exists, but I'm still looking for the check - hasattr(n, "class") is not working.